# error blockchain recive api code

Tags: php, api, callback, bitcoin, blockchain

as you see in the title 
i need help with bitcoin payments api
i have a website all i need is an api that generate a new address for each payment and send the amount that i specify and get a call back with an invoice_id and a link and a number
i did everything as mentioned on the blockchain api page not the wallet api
but i cant get it done because i dont recive a callback
i can generate address and the money come back to my address all the problem is i dont recive the callback to my url 
also when i test the URL manualy everything is working

anyone can help me or can give me a working version of blockchain api i use this [https://github.com/blockchain/receive_payment_php_demo]

Comment: Can you try to post [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As it is this question is to broad to answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to the receive payments API page here: https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive and put in your callback URL, as well as a bitcoin address. When you click 'submit', you can see an option to fire test callbacks to see if the blockchain server can interface properly with yours (and if not, what error message is generated).